# Texturing Mesh for Second Life

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm told you cannot texture and object in Blender and then upload the textured object into Second Life.

My work flow is *Object > Unwrap > UV Map to Photoshop for Textures > Assign UV Map to Object > Export to Collada*, selecting *SL/OpenSim Static > Upload to SL.*

Of course, the textures do not follow.  Am I missing a step?
If you can't upload a textured object, what is the use of the Operator Preset?

The other related issue is that when I upload an object to SL, in edit, I cannot select an individual face to apply a texture to.  It applies the texture to the entire object, regardless of selecting "Select Face."

I have mapped, not mapped, mapped each individual face, textured, untextured.  It always applies an texture to the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't is the simple answer. You have to upload your textures and apply them in world. As for selecting faces, in Blender you need to assign a "material" to the parts you want to call a "face" in Second Life. If I can attach a photo you will see an object created in Blender, material slots applied (Black,red, green, yellow, blue) and, each of those are faces 0-5 on the object in SL.

[image: Blender Object with Materials As Faces]